Android Studio エミュレータ起動時のエラーについて
環境
Windows 11 Pro
Android Studio koaka 2024.11
Delphi11
今後、Android開発で本エミュレータを使用したいと考えております。
エミュレータ
Pixel API35 2 arm64-v8a3
APILEvel 35
px 1080 x 2280 dp 393 x 830
Density 440 dpi
ABIList arm64-v8a
Size on disk 512BM
※ABIList X86_64 のｴﾐｭﾚｰﾀ　は正常に起動。
起動後のエラーメッセージ
Pixel API35 2 arm64-v8a3
the emulator pocess for AVD 
Pixel API35 2 arm64-v8a3 has teminated 

試したこと
エミュレータを削除して、再作成　Studio 再起動で試してもエラーになります。
Disk未使用 173GB
どなたか、解決方法わかる方おりませんか？
宜しくお願いします。
